# Soldering Table Legs?

Tags: metal, table, welding, soldering

Would it be ok to solder,brass or hard metal, to make table legs? Or Would the joint not be able to hold much weight?

Comment: What is "hard metal"? A properly designed solder joint will be very strong. I have such a solder joint hold while the attached steel failed.

Answer (score 1):

Solder? Very unlikely.  The bond is designed for electrical conductivity not physical strength (or, in the plumbing case, to achieve a certain strength via capillary action in a very small space).  But brazing, that could work, if you have the capability to heat the metal, such as a forge.  And welding of course is as strong as the metal you are welding itself.

Comment: Oh i see! Thank you.  Do you know if a propane torch can reach the temps to blaze harder metals such as steel?

Comment: Propane torch works inside of a forge (e.g. built from bricks), usually used together with forced air for higher efficiency. For hard-brazing, you need at least oxy-propane or oxy-acetylene torch and even oxy-propane does not work for each situation.

Answer (score 1):

A good quality "turbo torch" or an oxy-acetylene torch is needed for brazing. Also, you will need the correct type of brazing rod matched for the material you are brazing. A good brazed joint will take practice. It is not as easy as soldering

Answer (score 0):

If you are building workbench table from construction steel, e.g. square tubing, stick, MIG, or TIG welding is the way to go.